# Error converting string to int32

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following method works:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public string GetData(string year)
{
    Int32 iYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(iYear))
    {
        return "true";
    } else
    {
        return "false";
    }
}
```

But if I pass a year say 2015 as a string, the following code doesn't work.

```
using System;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
public string output = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Params["callback"] != null)
    {
        output = Request.Params["callback"] + "('" + GetData(Request.Params["year"]) + "')";
    }
}

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public string GetData(string year)
{
    int iYear = Convert.ToInt32(year);

    if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(iYear))
    {
        return "true";
    } else {
        return "false";
    }
}
}
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out my mistake.  I'm passing year as a string to an jQuery Ajax call.

Any ideas why?

Joe

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery or Ajax?!

Comment: Have you attempted to debug your web page?

Comment: Can you explain what is not working here?

Comment: Are you getting the wrong value back (true rather than false) or is the call failing?

Comment: Also, I thought that page methods that were to be used as web methods had to be `static`.  I'm sure someone can correct me if that has changed.

Comment: I'm getting 500 (Internal Server Error) when I try to debug it in Web Inspector. I'm writing a simple mobile app to check for leap year. I have an html page with a form that makes a jQuery Ajax call to Asp.Net page located on a remote web server. The web server takes the year, checks if it leap year or not and return true or false string back to mobile app. Otherwise the asp.net page is blank which is why I'm having trouble debugging this.  If I view the asp.net page in browser, I do not get any errors.

Comment: i wonder if changing `int iYear` to `int32 iYear` makes sense since you use Int32 on the working version :)

Comment: By converting int iYear to int32 iYear = Convert.ToInt32(year), VS complains that the type or namespace int32 could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error, the error was in the Ajax call, I was enclosing the date in quotes. Thanks all for your support and help.

This is what I had 
    data: { year: "' + $('#txtYear').val() + '"}

When I removed quotes, it worked. 
    data: { year: +$('#txtYear').val() }